# Codeigniter: How to get the count from second table while iterating the first table values

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a two table,`question` and `answer`  .

```
question
-----------
question_id PK Auto_Incr  
question    varchar... 
votes       int


answer
------------
answer_id    PK  Auto_icre
question_id  FK refrences question  
content      longtext
```

I have several answer for each questions,I am iterating my question list,but i don't know how can show the count of number answer for each question,in the same time when i am iterating my question table data in my view page.

---

Table Data structure data:

```
 question
-----------
 question_id    question          votes
    1           what's name?       0
    2           where you?         3

answer 
----------
 answer_id      question_id        content
    4              2                 India
    5              2                 Nepal
    6              2                 Pakistan
    7              1                 Mr Osama Binladan
```

---

So,from my above shown table structure, **i want output to be display in my view page containing below data**

```
    ------------------------------------------
      Question    : what's name?
      votes       :  0
     No. of answer:  1 

    -------------------------------------------
      Question    : where you? 
      votes       :  3
     No. of answer:  3 
    -------------------------------------------
```

I have problem, how can i show the no. of answer(count answer) for each particular question?

***Update model:***

```
         //-------------------------Get hot question by------------------------------ 
        public function fetch_allquestions($limit, $start) {
            $this->load->database(); 
            $this->db->limit($limit, $start);   

            $select =array(
                'q.*',
                'COUNT(a.answer_id) AS `Answers`'
                );
    $this->db->select($select);
    $this->db->from('question q');
    $this->db->group_by('q.question_id');
    $this->db->join('answer a', 'answer.question_id = q.question_id'); 
      $this->db->join('userdetails ', 'userdetails.user_id = question.user_id'); //this is not working fine
    $query = $this->db->get();  


       if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                foreach ($query->result() as $row)
                {
                    $data[] = $row;
                }
                return $data;
            }
            return false;
       }
```

Comment: please post a sample question and its answer and desired output

Comment: i see a mistake here `$this->db->join('answer', 'answer.question_id = question.question_id');` You are not aliasing answer change it `$this->db->join('answer a', 'answer.question_id = question.question_id');`

Comment: That is fine, but now i have problem with maping my userdetails table. I tried the above model code, but getting error `Severity: Notice ,undefine property $user_id`  .Why?

Comment: see the edited model in my answer

Comment: Working fine but its returning only one row from my question, its not returning whole rows from my table `question`  I tried to print ` print_r("Number of rows=".$query->num_rows());` But its returning only one result. But in my table there are 26 results.. Why this?

Comment: @raheelshan working fine.Actually my  `question` table data are entered manually,thats why i was getting error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your structure is not fine you should change it.

```
question
-----------
id   PK Auto_Incr  
question    varchar...
votes       int

answer
------------
answer_id  PK  Auto_icre
content    longtext 
question_id FK refrences question table
```

And now you can easily count them with this query

```
SELECT 
    q.*,
    COUNT(a.answer_id) AS `Answers`
FROM question q
LEFT JOIN answer a ON a.question_id = q.id
GROUP BY q.id

$query  =   "
            SELECT 
                q.*,
                COUNT(a.answer_id) AS `Answers`
            FROM question q
            LEFT JOIN answer a ON a.question_id = q.id
            GROUP BY q.id";
$this->db->query($query);
```

Or

```
$select =array(
            'q.*',
            'COUNT(a.answer_id) AS `Answers`'
            );
$this->db->select($select);
$this->db->from('question q');
$this->db->group_by('q.id');
$this->db->join('answer a', 'answer.question_id = question.id'); 
$query = $this->db->get();
```

View to display

```
<?php
foreach ($query3 as $row) 
{
?>
    <?php echo $row->votes ?>
    <?php echo $row->question    ?>
    <?php echo $row->Answers  ?>
<?php 
}
?>
```

You should note in query i have assigned `Answers` as alias so in view you need to use `$row->Answers` to display count.

New EDITs

Your model should be like this

```
public function fetch_allquestions($limit, $start) 
{
    $this->load->database(); 
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);   
    $select =array(
                    'question.*',
                    'userdetails.*'
                    'COUNT(answer.answer_id) AS `Answers`',
            );

    $this->db->select($select);
    $this->db->from('question');
    $this->db->join('answer', 'answer.question_id = question.question_id'); 
    $this->db->join('userdetails', 'userdetails.user_id = question.user_id');
    $this->db->group_by('question.question_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();  

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query->result();// returning result is enough you dont have to loop
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mistakly i posted, wrong structure of my table . Now i updated , please check my updated question.

Comment: @BurlsWillis all the same i have already given the answer that fits your need. Have you checked it?

Comment: yes, Now how can i show the count value in my view page along with the question table field value(as shown in my sample output)?

Comment: also you forget to mention my join of  `$this->db->join('userdetails', 'userdetails.user_id = question.user_id');`

Comment: Sorry! Error(I tried the second one):  `A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'a.answer_id' in 'field list'

SELECT `q`.*, COUNT(a.answer_id) AS `Answers` FROM (`question` q) JOIN `answer` ON `answer`.`question_id` = `question`.`question_id` GROUP BY `q`.`question_id` LIMIT 5

Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330`

Comment: put your primary key of answers table

Comment: Actually,its not working ,now i found the problem why its not showing me the other row of my question table. It is showing only the question which have answer .Those question which have no answer it is not counting. how can i modify my above code to meet my new requirement? –

Comment: Solved it like `$this->db->join('answer','answer.question_id = question.question_id', 'left');`